# Bing Maps api Problems geocoding addresses with "#"

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, geocoding, bing-api

With Bing Maps API, is it possible to geocode the addresses with "#"

Example -
This geocodes OK with Address:

> 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy APT 23, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA

But if I replace the Apt with #,
1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy #23, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA
 the result is an error.

This is my url:

```
var strAddress ;

string url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + 
strAddress + "&key=" + key;
```

I tried using 
encodeUriComponent,
 System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode,
Uri.EscapeUriString,

Like this 
string url = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + 
    System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strAddress) + "&key=" + key;

none of them worked for me!

Basically we are do geocoding in  **Plugin** but not javascript.
Could anyone please help me?
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Are you concerned with the URL encoding of the hash or the fact that bing maps doesn't appropriately handle addresses with a hash in them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to escape the `#` character to `%23`, which then prevents it from starting a hash component of the URI. As an untested example:

```
stringUrl = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + 
             encodeURIComponent( strAddress) + "&key=" +
             encodeURIComponent( key);
```